# Email should come under same convestaion

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am sending email using php mailer and email is going fine to the inbox

but next time when i reply back instead of email coming to under same conversation it create a new email even it should show all the email subject

any one has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The email you send via php must have a header

```
Reply-To: <from-email-address>
From: <from-email-address>
```

as well as a

```
To: <destination-email-address>
```

header line for it to appear as a conversation thread.

Also the subject line should be the same or be the same with a prepended 'Re: '